# Not able to fetch the data for G+ using gigya

Tags: callback, google-plus, gigya

We have created the gigya account. Using the same gigya account we have created the Twitter, facebook & G+ account(Reference : http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/82_Socialize_Setup/005_Opening_External_Applications/16_Google).

We are able to get the user & there friends info using gigya for FB & Twitter, however we are not able to get the users and there friends info using gigya for G+ account. 
We have checked that G+ account set properly(As we are able to get the G+ account info using G+ API).
Can anyone help us to resolve the issue(why we are not able to fetch the data for G+ account)

### Code Snippet :

```
GSRequest request = new GSRequest(apiKey, secretKey,
        "socialize.getFriendsInfo", false);
request.setParam(Parameters.uid, uid);
request.setParam(Parameters.format, "json");
GSResponse response = request.send(timeout);
String response_json = response.getResponseText();
System.out.println("Friends Info : ");
System.out.println("#### "+response_json);
```

### Output :

Friends Info : Getting an blank friend list array ...

{  "friends": [],  "oldestDataUpdatedTimestamp": 0,  "oldestDataAge": 3417602649,  "statusCode": 200,  "errorCode": 0,  "statusReason": "OK",  "callId": "d383b76ff5ab4822899577f9cd15f3ea"}

Similarly for profile details : Not getting basic details like nickname & other attributes...

Thank you in advanced

Comment: is there any code to share here?  I'm really unsure what you've tried and what you're not receiving?

Comment: @Anthony : Thanks for your quick response ...
I have added the code snippet and output in summary.

Answer (score 0):

On the Gigya API key you are testing with, in the Gigya Console to to the Settings >> Permissions screen and make sure to check the "Enable extended social functionality (including access to Google+ circles)" permission. Then try logging back in again using the showLoginUI with the G+ user you are calling getFriendsInfo for. The next time you call getFriendsInfo it should return the friends information.

If that still doesn't work, try it with a new G+ user who hasn't signed into that API key before.

Comment: Yes, I have created new user as well as I asked existing user to relogin using showLoginUI. And then for both the users I got the profile and friends information.
However I am able to get that data only for limited time(approximately 1hour)  And again after 1hour I am not getting profile & friends information. 

We just come to know that : the googleplus oauth token has a limited lifetime and so we need to log a user in before requesting the list of contacts.

Comment: So I need confirmation for some more points, mentioned below :   
-        For Google+ issue :  
o    Is this limitation of the gigya free account that we are using?  
o    And if we move to paid account or something else, can we get the data forever using same authtoken?  
-        For how many days the auth token for Twitter and FB are valid.  
-        Is there any mechanism using which the auth tokens can be utilized for unlimited or long (~1 year) period for all 3 social sites(Facebook, Twitter and Google+)?